# JOIN SQL MULTIPLES TABLAS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas,

Quisiera hacer una pregunta, esta consulta sql está funcionando, pero repite los registros, alguna sugerencia o corrección

```
select 
f.periodo 'PERIODO_INFORMADO', s.rut_emp 'RUT_EMPRESA', e.nom_empresa 'DESCRIPCION_RUT',r.id_reg 'REGION',
r.nom_reg'DESCRIPCION_REGION', s.cod_sist 'SISTEMA', s.nom_sist 'DESCRIPCION_SISTEMA',f.cod_obra 'CODIGO_OBRA',
f.nom_obra'NOMBRE_OBRA', f.anyo_obra'AÑO_CONSTRUCCION', eu.id_est'ESTADO_USO', eu.nom_est'DESCRIPCION_ESTADO', sr.id_secrio'SECCION_RIO',
sr.nom_secrio'DESCRIPCION_SECCION',f.num_fuente'FUENTE', f.nom_fuente'DESCRIPCION_FUENTE', f.cota'COTA', d.id_dsr'DESARENADOR', d.nom_dsr'DESCRIPCION_DESARENADOR',
f.caudal'CAUDAL_DISEÑO', t.id_tc'TIPO_CAPTACION', t.nom_tc'DESCRIPCION_CAPTACION',f.otro_tipo'OTRO_TIPO_CAPTACION', f.barrera_long'LONGITUD_BARRERA', 
f.barrera_alt'ALTURA_BARRERA', f.cap_op'CAPACIDAD_OPERATIVA', tlm.id_tlm'TELEMETRIA', tlm.nom_tlm'DESCRIPCION_TELEMETRIA', 
tlc.id_tlc'TELECONTROL', tlc.nom_tlc'DESCRIPCION TELECONTROL', f.utm_n'UTM_NORTE', f.utm_e'UTM_ESTE', f.vigencia'VIGENCIA'
from fam101 f
join 
localidad l on f.cod_local=l.cod_local
join 
region r on r.id_reg = l.id_reg
join 
sis_tarifario s on r.id_reg = s.id_reg 
join
empresa e on s.rut_emp = e.rut_emp
join 
est_uso eu on f.id_est = eu.id_est
join
sec_rio sr on f.id_secrio = sr.id_secrio
join 
desarenador d on f.id_dsr = d.id_dsr
join
tipo_cap_rio t on f.id_tc = t.id_tc
join 
tlmetria tlm on f.id_tlm = tlm.id_tlm
join 
tlcontrol tlc on f.id_tlc = tlc.id_tlc
```

Comment: Podrías añadir un group by para agrupar según lo que necesites

Comment: probaste con `SELECT DISTINT` ?

Comment: A menos que sepas concientemente que estás duplicando datos por una razón, cualquiera de las dos sugerencias anteriores lo único que hacen es esconder el problema que es de lógica de datos que solo tu puedes llegar a descubrir. Como sugerencia, te diría prueba comentar todos los joins menos uno y volver a probar, luego comentas el anterior y descomentas otro y así con todos hasta encontrar la tabla o tablas que hacen "duplicar" la información. Luego hay que entender la lógica de las tablas, ver si se debe modificar  el `ON` agregando algún filtro, o hacer una subconsulta agrupada, etc.

Answer (score 1):

@PatricioMoracho Tiene toda la razón. Pero, a tu solicitud de alguna sugerencia, pues si quieres evitar que se repitan ciertos registros desde su inserción, te recomendaría que en la definición de la tabla crees índices únicos:

```
ALTER TABLE `TablaEjemplo` 
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX `indice_prueba` (`campo1`, `campo2`, `campo3`);
```

Esto evita que se inserten registros en una tabla que repitan un patrón descrito por el índice único. Asegúrate de no dejar campos sin tomar en cuenta o tomar campos de sobra y pasarte de estricto.

Esto te puede ahorrar mucho tiempo en lugar de hacer `group by` o `distinct` (en caso de que tengas tablas con más de cientos de miles de registros). Incluso por paz mental al asegurarte de tener cierto control de los campos en los registros introducidos en tus tablas. Además de que evitando duplicados en tablas que van a tener muchos registros como emisiones de pólizas, registros de visitas, etc., te vas a ahorrar mucho almacenamiento y (por lo mismo del uso de group by o distinct) tiempo de ejecución.

Si quieres eliminar ese índice por algún motivo, puedes correr la siguiente consulta:

```
ALTER TABLE `TablaEjemplo` 
  DROP INDEX indice_prueba;
```

Y volverlo a crear, etc. Si quieres ver los campos que usa ese índice puedes utilizar:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TablaEjemplo'
  AND INDEX_NAME = 'indice_prueba';
```

Answer (score 0):

Te aparece más de una consulta debido a que hay una relación de uno a muchos en alguno de tus `join` con la tabla principal de consulta `fam101`.

Primero verifica si los `join` están bien.

Suponiendo que haya dos registros en la tabla `sec_rio` al hacer, por ejemplo, un  group by `f.codigo` te saldría una sola fila por cada registro de `fam101`, pero de los dos registros de `sec_rio` solo mostraría uno. Por lo general el que primero fue insertado en base de datos y se omitiría información del segundo registro.

Si necesitas la información de ambos registros, puedes hacer uso de la función `group_concat(sr.id_secrio)` en la selección de columnas antes  del `from` para los dos valores aparezcan separados por comas en un mismo registro.